# Why does rsync keep skipping the directory I want to sync?

Tags: shell, centos, rsync, synchronization

I want to sync a directory between my Mac High Sierra machine and a CentOs 7 machine, excluding a certain file.  I have tried the below

```
(venv) localhost:dental davea$ rsync -e 'ssh -p 7822' --exclude='dental/wsgi.py' ~/Documents/workspace/dental/ laredotornado@remotedomen.com:/home/laredotornado
skipping directory /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/dental/.
```

I don't quite understand why it is always skipping the file I want to sync with.  I have verified both the local and remote driectories exist but don't know where else to check as to why things are falling down.

Comment: Are you expecting it to do a recursive sync? Did you forget `--archive` or `-a`?

Comment: Are you running this from the `dental` directory? If you just want to exclude that file and you are already in the `dental` directory then you can specify the file itself with `--exclude 'wsgi.py'` as the path is already relative as far as `rsync` is concerned.

Comment: @Kusalananda, that was it!  Including "-a" moves stuff along.

Comment: @Kusalananda Please propose your comment as answer and help close this question.

Comment: @Atul I'm treating it as a typo. You may want to write a proper answer, explaining what's going on and how adding `-a` solves it, if you wish.

Answer (score 19):

The rsync command didnt include the `/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/dental/` directory as the `-a` was not used. Adding `-a` flag also includes the `-r` (recursive) flag in the operation thus allowing the directory to be part of the process.